# How to expire or disable link once the response on that particular link is submitted by user?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, signed-url

Currently working on a personal project and solving a scenario where on submitting the form a signed URL(action link) is emailed to user, once that link is opened by user and form in that URL is submitted, what I am trying to achieve and facing issue in development is, if anyone again opens that link after submission of form they are shown a screen like which maybe saying your response is submitted. Any hint about that does this kind of functionality is possible to be built with Laravel or which topic I should be searching for that can make me able to understand how to solve such scenarios. Any suggestion or hint would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @brombeer Thanks for your suggestion, but I have no where asked for referring me to that documentation as I have mentioned already that I have implemented signed URL and its working.

Comment: The title of your post is "_How to expire or disable link once the response on that particular link is submitted by user?_" - if that's not what you're actually asking you might want to change it. What _is_ your actual question then? If it is "_if anyone again opens that link after submission of form they are shown a screen like which maybe saying your response is submitted_" you might want to read a little further, section "_Responding To Invalid Signed Routes_"

Answer (score 2):

This is a common operation in laravel and you can handle this easily with controllers.
The standard way is:

you should create a link and save it on your database. Add a field named **isSubmitted** . Also, I highly recommend you to have expiration_date field for that link in database.

Create a new migration with artisan using this command:

```
php artisan make:migration links
```

Then, add your favorite fileds to migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class LinksTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('links', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();

            $table->text("url");
            $table->boolean("is_submitted")->default(false);

            $table->timestamp("expiration_data")->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('links');
    }
}
```

In next step, when you are submitting that form, in your controller, change the status of **isSubmitted** field and save it on the database again. On next call of url,  you can handle the request according to **isSubmitted** field